# Reading data from MySQL JPA Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I cant get displayed data from MySQL. It shows only empty object [] when I go to /employee.

Data from mysql is not stored in repository. How to store it???

And one more question:
What does CommandLineRunner do?

Employee.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")

public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
   private String firstName;
   @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
   private String lastName;

   protected Employee(){}

   public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

   public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "Employee[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
            id, firstName, lastName);
}


}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
EmployeeRepository repository;

@RequestMapping("/employee")
@ResponseBody
public List<Employee> getAll(){
    return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

EmployeeLoader.java

```
@Component
public class EmployeeLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

private static final Logger log =          Logger.getLogger(EmployeeLoader.class.getName());


@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository repository;


@Autowired
public EmployeeLoader(EmployeeRepository repository){
    this.repository = repository;
}




@Override
public void run(String...string) throws Exception {
    log.info("Employee found with findAll():");
    log.info("-------------------------------");
    for (Employee emp : repository.findAll()) {
        log.info(emp.toString());
    }
    log.info("");

    }

}
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

 public List<Employee> findAll();
}
```

SQL Data

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Mark      | Leeeeeee |
|  2 | John      | Smith    |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://linktodb:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

Comment: Is your EmployeeRepository class annotated with @Repository?

Comment: Yes, it does. will add here

Comment: Is your problem with your controller or with your repo. Does repository.findAll() returns anything?

Comment: How to test it? For now is just empty object. I believe that data from db is not saved in repo?

Comment: In the same controller just print the size of the repository.findAll() results

Comment: it is empty.    {
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 0,
    "totalPages": 0,
    "number": 0
  }
}

Comment: What is your log output. Does it print any ``emp.toString()``? Did you try calling ``localhost:8080/employee``?

Comment: Check you are connecting to the same db that contains those 2 rows, otherwise without full source code its hard to tell where your problem may be

Comment: Output for localhost:8080/employee  is [ ]

Comment: this is all code that I have

Comment: If this is all code that you have, you might be missing DB connection setting. Try adding ``spring.datasource.url``, ``spring.datasource.username``, ``spring.datasource.password`` to your ``application.properties``

Comment: it is in application.property

Comment: Can you update your question with your ``application.properties``

Comment: problem is : data from mysql is not stored in repository.

Comment: I've just cloned your code and everything worked fine in my computer. Could you upload your project to github or somewhere?

Comment: never used github. dont know how to upload. let me try